# Creating a printable form with varying page count and automatic page breaks

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a printable "invoice" form with a varying number of pages. Each page should have a repeating header and footer, and in between are the invoices' positions.

It would be great if WPF could create an automatic page break between the positions. Is that somehow possible?

In another project, I've created a more "static" printable form which consists of a Canvas, exactly in size of a A4 page, with nested Layout frames and controls on it.  This canvas can be printed, and it is working great, I like the concept.

But how about dynamically varying content with a varying number of records, and page breaks?

Can this be realized in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into flow documents. These allow you to create document style content and can be displayed in a few different WPF controls. The `FlowDocumentReader` control has a "Page" viewing mode that might be what you are looking for. Here are some links to get you started:

[Flow Document Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)
[FlowDocumentReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx). But this is exactly the reason of existence of various reporting systems, to let you define something abstract, what then will be split into pages with headers, footers, automatic table splitting, etc.

I'd recommend to use something like `PDFsharp` (it has Migradoc for this reason). Viewer can be embedded, but much easier to simply run external pdf-viewer, the only task left is to generate pdf itself.